# Manim - Strange Corner Calculation Behavior After Moving Square

Tags: python, manim

Hey so I'm just starting to learn manim but I encountered some strange behavior. If I get the coordinates of a square and draw them, they align with the square. But, if I try to move / shift / align_to / next_to the square, then draw the corners again, they no longer align with the square. It works in all directions, for all scales, and what's quite weird is that the offset seems to be proportional to how far the square is shifted. [image: Picture of behavior!]

Here is my (distilled) code:

```
def square_and_corners(square, color):
    # Calculate the corners of the square
    DL = square.get_left() + square.get_bottom()
    DR = square.get_right() + square.get_bottom()
    UL = square.get_left() + square.get_top()
    UR = square.get_right() + square.get_top()

    # Add corners and square
    self.add(Dot(DL, color=color), Dot(DR, color=color),
             Dot(UL, color=color), Dot(UR, color=color))
    self.add(square)

# No moving
square1 = Square(2, color=WHITE)
square_and_corners(square1, WHITE)

# Move to RIGHT
square2 = Square(2, color=RED)
square2.move_to(RIGHT)
square_and_corners(square2, RED)

# align to the left of the central square
square3 = Square(2, color=GREEN)
square3.next_to(square1, LEFT)
square_and_corners(square3, GREEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution Code

```
class SquareScene(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        def square_and_corners(square, color):
            DL = square.get_left() + square.get_bottom()
            DR = square.get_right() + square.get_bottom()
            UL = square.get_left() + square.get_top()
            UR = square.get_right() + square.get_top()
            g = [DL,DR,UL,UR]
            G = VGroup()
            for s in g:
                dot = Dot(point = s,color = color)
                G.add(dot)
            G.add(square)
            return G

# No moving
        square1 = Square(side_length = 2)
        self.add(square_and_corners(square1, WHITE))

# Move to RIGHT
        square2 = Square(side_length = 2).set_stroke(color = RED)
        a = square_and_corners(square2, RED)
        self.add(a.move_to(RIGHT))

# align to the left of the central square
        square3 = Square(side_length = 2, color=GREEN)
        b = square_and_corners(square3, GREEN)
        self.add(b.next_to(square1, LEFT))

# You can move only the square if you want (or any mobject in the VGroup)
        square4 = Square(side_length = 2, color=BLUE)
        b = square_and_corners(square4, BLUE)
        self.add(b.next_to(square1, UP))
        self.add(square4.next_to(square1,DOWN))
```

### Details

The best way to deal with a group of mobjects in manim is by grouping them in a VGroup() this way enables you to animate all the mobjects in the group or any mobject you want separately and reduces the number of errors while rendering and problems that appear in the animation and reduces the lines you write to make your animation and it is pretty easy to deal with in iterations.

### The Output

[image]